# Android CardView setBackground as BitmapDrawable when API <21

Tags: android, bitmap, android-recyclerview

I have a problem when I am trying to `setBackground()` of a `CardView` programatically in KitKat.When the application is running on Android L there is no problem in my code :

```
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(appContext.getResources(), bitmap);
if (cardView != null) {                
    cardView.setBackground(drawable);
}
```

But when it runs in API older than Android L I get this error: `android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RoundRectDrawableWithShadow.`

I found out that this is known issue and there is work around where you want to set a colour as a background of the card, but is there any solution with which I could set the bitmap for background programatically? Do you have any idea how could I create `RoundRectDrawableWithShadow` from my `BitmapDrawable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you have any idea how could I create RoundRectDrawableWithShadow from my BitmapDrawable?

*Don't do it unless you wish to rewrite your own `CardView` implementation.*

`RoundRectDrawableWithShadow` is a package private class used to take the *color* you supplied by `app:cardBackgroundColor` or `setCardBackgroundColro(int)` and wrap it in a rounded rectangle with shadow to produce a drawable.

Since elevation was introduced in API 21 the shadow is painted as part of `CardView` background drawable on prior platforms so *you can't set your own background via `setBackground(*)`*.

> is there any solution with which I could set the bitmap for background programatically?

You could put a `View`, `*Layout`, etc. in the card and set a rounded drawable background on it. It will not be effective performance-wise though.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawable.html

Comment: About putting a ImageView into the cardview - I am on the same way.So in conclusion you can`t set Bitmap for background programatically in version below Android L, am I right?

Comment: Bottom line is: You shouldn't call `setBackground` on a `CardView` at all. On Lollipop almost all its modification methods (radius, maxElevation...) rely on the background being `RoundRectDrawable` which is again package private. So yeah, if you absolutely need something else than solid color, go with a `View.setBackground` (you don't need an `ImageView` for that).

Comment: hi, can you help me with a similar problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31558251/android-how-to-keep-corner-radius-while-setting-a-background-drawable

Answer (score 1):

So yeah, if you absolutely need something else than solid color, go with a View.setBackground