# Android: How to keep corner radius while setting a background drawable?

Tags: android, material-design, android-cardview

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/card_view"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  card_view:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
  card_view:cardElevation="12dp">

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    .....

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This is what I set in layout.xml

I'd like to programmatically change the background of the card at runtime.

```
CardView card =(CardView) findViewById(R.id.card_view);
card.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.card1);
```

This will set all radius corners to 0dp. I'd like to keep the radius and the  background drawable.

Answer (score 3):

Use `card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFFFFFF"` instead of `android:background="#FFFFFFFF"`
Programatically use, `card.setCardBackgroundColor(color)` instead of `card.setBackgroundColor(color)`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `CardView` you can set background resource for layout containing by that `cardview` like following.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/card_view"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  card_view:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
  card_view:cardElevation="12dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            .....
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and

```
LinearLayout myLayout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
myLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.card1);
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: it works for android 5+ but not for minor versions. The drawable is in a rectangle, leaving white margins from cardview